# application after being published stops updating the update panel after few minutes

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, updatepanel, outputcache

This is the code which updates my updatepanel regularly, it runs very well on local for a long period of time but after being published, it works good for 15-20 minutes , may be lesser sometimes. but after that it does not update the contents inside updatepanel automatically, but on a button click it updates the updatepanel with new data. I suggest it might be the case of outputcache. What is the problem?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       setInterval(function () {

           __doPostBack('updateComments', '');
           // document.getElementById("btnExitChatRoom").click();
       }, 5000);

   </script>
```

Comment: C'mon......someone answer this.please

Answer (score 0):

You need to call 'setInterval' on document ready.
Below is the example:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
  $(document).ready(    
    function ()
    {          
         setInterval('myFun()', 5000);      
    });
    function myFun() 
    {         
         __doPostBack('updateComments', '');     
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: And what is the need to do so. How will it benefit me. Please Elaborate a bit